# Django, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_pg'

Tags: django, postgresql

Can someone provide more details on setting up and utilizing django_pg.  I would like to use the *array functionality*.

By following the setup of two simple steps from here:
https://django-pgfields.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Results in this error:

```
(environment) jeff@jeff-computer:~/environment/projectA$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/jeff/environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/jeff/environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
django.setup()
File "/home/jeff/environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/jeff/environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/home/jeff/environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/home/jeff/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_pg'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to do `pip install django-pgfields` to install it.

However, you probably shouldn’t be using this package. It hasn’t had any updates for years, so won’t support modern versions of Django.

Since Django 1.8,
Django comes with [`django.contrib.postgres`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/), which might provide the Postgres functionality that you require.